# Handling very close vertices of cloth cloth interaction (twinkling holes behavior)

Tags: android, opengl-es, precision

I have three different OBJs in my scene, a body, and a shirt and pant simulated over that body (rendered in that order).

Rendering was showing inner shirt outside the pants at some points in the form of some 'holes' on my test android devices while it works just fine on the desktops.

[image]

I guessed that some points are very close to each other and hence tried [highp](http://ramisantina.com/blog/2013/06/mediump-vs-highp-precision-on-embedded-gpus/) for precision and it started working fine on some of my devices (Surprisingly it doesn't work on an year old Nexus!)

[image]

Q. Have I identified the correct problem or it could be because of any other possible reason as well. Is there any way I can solve this issue on all devices ?

Q. Can I somehow at least get to know which GPUs will have this problem so that I can target my APK accordingly ?

**Using :**

Android 5.0

OpenGL ES 3.0

---

Edit:

Just in case its of any help, when rotating the scene, or zooming in-out, these holes show a 'twinkling behavior'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I seem to have solved this.

I quote from the [opengl archives](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm) :

> **12.040 Depth buffering seems to work, but polygons seem to bleed through polygons that are in front of them. What's going on?**
>
> You may have configured your zNear and zFar clipping planes in a way
>   that severely limits your depth buffer precision. Generally, this is
>   caused by a zNear clipping plane value that's too close to 0.0. As the
>   zNear clipping plane is set increasingly closer to 0.0, the effective
>   precision of the depth buffer decreases dramatically. Moving the zFar
>   clipping plane further away from the eye always has a negative impact
>   on depth buffer precision, but it's not one as dramatic as moving the
>   zNear clipping plane.

Same page has lots of details about bounding boxes and related issues. Nice read.

I had a huge size BB. I reduced the size and moved camera nearer to the objects, the issue is resolved from all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

`highp` support is not mandatory, and AFAICT it's also not an 'extension', so you can't query it and support for it is also not recorded in GLES capability databases like http://opengles.gpuinfo.org/

You can query the precision of the shader using `glGetShaderPrecisionFormat` (  http://docs.gl/es3/glGetShaderPrecisionFormat )

Of course it's up to your application to know what actual precision is actually needed. And this is at runtime, no way to know in advance.